# Cursor property with custom url not displaying correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, cursor

I am using the CSS `cursor` property with custom images specified with URLs.

However, when doing this on Chrome, white dots appear around the cursor image.

If we look at the image below, you can see the problem on google chrome.

[image]
[image]

This does not happen on other browsers. Such as firefox:

[image]
[image]

Here is the link to the cursor images used:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tikyJ.jpg

I thought originally that the issue would be that semi-transparency is used in the image. But the image has no semi-transparency at all.

What is going on here, and how would I fix something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a link to the graphics you're using?

Comment: @tedmiston I've updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this example using Chrome 52.0 on Mac OS X 10.11, but I am not seeing the jagged white edges.  Does this snippet show the jagged white edges for you?

```css
.cursor-test {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

#cursor-test-1 {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: url('http://i.imgur.com/jaYSPxo.png'), auto;
}

#cursor-test-2 {
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: url('http://i.imgur.com/aFU13SN.png'), auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor-test-1" class="cursor-test"></div>
<div id="cursor-test-2" class="cursor-test"></div>
```

Update: Here's an animated gif screenshot of how it looks for me.  I attempted to capture a regular screenshot, but OS X seems to hide custom CSS cursors in screenshots.

[image: custom cursor hover]

Comment: Yes, I am experiencing these issues still! It is not as noticeable with cursor 1 though. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @DavidCallanan I added a screenshot to the answer.  Is that similar or different than how it looks for you?  Also, what browser + OS are you using?

Comment: It is quite a bit worse than that. I'm using Chrome 51.0.2704.79 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Comment: @DavidCallanan When I put the provided images into an editor, it looks like they do have alpha transparency.  Digging a little deeper it seems Chromium has had [issues with alpha transparent custom cursors](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/cd0a8ae72380dc461eea58084325d9d981942192) in the recent past (though they appear to be solved today).  The snippet I've included looks about the same in Safari and Firefox for me.  Can you check a few other browsers to see if it's consistent for you?

Comment: I've checked Firefox, and it is fine with Firefox, so it must be a chrome thing. I could probably remove the alpha transparency and see if that fixes it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just found out my version of chrome is a developer build. I hope that is not the problem.